# Google ad manager for publishers DoubleClick > multiple sizes per slot

Tags: google-ad-manager

i know that i show ads with:

```
GA_googleFillSlot(AD_UNIT_NAME_300x250);
```

But what if i want to show either 300x250 or 300x600 in the same position but not both of them at once?

Cheers,
Karington!

Answer (score 0):

Google defines ad units like this:

```
googletag.cmd.push(function () {
    googletag.defineSlot('/1111111/BLAH_ROS_Island', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1111110-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
    googletag.enableServices();
});
```

You can provide two units in the same definition, try it

```
googletag.cmd.push(function () {
    googletag.defineSlot('/1111111/BLAH_ROS_Island', [[300, 600], [300, 250]], 'div-gpt-ad-1111110-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
    googletag.enableServices();
});
```

So from
**[300, 250]**
to
**[[300, 600], [300, 250]]**